# LPARAM keeps changing in TVITEM

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, treeview, lparam

I'm adding a bunch of items to a treeview, with a string stored in `lParam`, like this:

```
TVITEM tvi = {sizeof(TVITEM)};
tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;
tvi.pszText = const_cast<char *> (txt0.c_str());  // Display text
tvi.cchTextMax = sizeof(tvi.pszText);
tvi.lParam = (LPARAM) add0.c_str();  // A file path string

TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis;
tvis.item = tvi;
tvis.hParent = hti0;  // Some parent node

TreeView_InsertItem(tvw_filelist_, &tvis);
```

After I finish adding all of them, I come back and check (in a different function):

```
TVITEM tvi = {sizeof(TVITEM)};
char buf[200];
tvi.pszText = buf;
tvi.cchTextMax = 200;
tvi.hItem = htiTemp;  // htiTemp is the current node in the iteration
tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_PARAM;

// Retrieve; address is stored in lParam.
TreeView_GetItem(tvw_filelist_, &tvi);

char out[200];
strcpy(out, "Checking: PSZTEXT: ");
strcat(out, tvi.pszText);
strcat(out, ". LPARAM: ");
strcat(out, (const char *) tvi.lParam);
```

...and the LPARAM has been reset to the value of the last item added.

So, if I add items `one, two, three, four` with similar `lParam` values, then after I check they all have `lParam` of `four`.  (Sometimes, there's garbage values.)

There's obviously a problem here, and it's probably really easy to fix, but after several hours of experimenting I can't find what's wrong.  Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tvi.lParam = (LPARAM) add0.c_str();` this is the problem. `tvi.lParam` is a pointer type.

FROM MSDN :

> LPARAM This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows: typedef LONG_PTR
>   LPARAM;

what is a `add0`? I guess it is a local variable.  If the function return, this `add0` var will be deconstructed, and `tvi.lParam` is pointed to the inter buff of string `add0`, and now this inter buff is freed, so `tvi.lParam` points to the garbage.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it is local.  Thanks for the tip - any recommendations on fixing it?

Comment: Please also check txt0: tvi.pszText = const_cast<char *> (txt0.c_str());  // Display text

Comment: I was going to ask about that, but I haven't noticed any strange behavior.  That's a pointer too, right?

Comment: tvi.lParam = (LPARAM)_strdup(add0.c_str()), this will alloc the memory and duplicated the string. Do remember to call on free the tvi.lParam after finishing using treeview

Comment: Thanks, that works! Just to confirm, you mean call `void free ( void * ptr );` on all the `lParam`s, if the treeview is discarded before the application is destroyed?

Comment: Not exactly, if the memory the LParam points is allocated by your code, you can call free on it, also, avoid call free twice since it cause unknown problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing an address in `tvi.lParam`. This is the address of the string `add0`.

If `add0` goes out of scope  then the address becomes invalid. This is the reason you see different values.

You must assign `tvi.lParam` an address which is always available. Make the string a global variable or class member variable.

Again, you will need one string for each tree node. So you will need to maintain an array of strings. If you have only one string then the same address will have a different value, like you are observing in case of one, two, three, four.

Thanks.

Comment: Darn scope gets me every time.  Thanks and I'll have a look!